# Clean query strings urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am in need of help with the damn htaccess file, RegEx just confuses me I can handle the basic redirects but once it gets into query strings I lose it.

So here is the problem

I am trying to clean up my urls so I want to take the original path:

```
http://localhost/webcampaign/projects/project.php?id=1917-Bungalow
```

and have it show up has

```
http://localhost/webcampaign/projects/1917-Bungalow
```

this is a photo of file structure to give a better idea

[image]

I have all projects in an array set up like this

```
$projects = array();
$projects["1917-Bungalow"] = array(
 "name" => "1917 Bungalow",
 "heroClass" => "hero-bungalow",
 "mainImg" => BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_main.jpg",
 "previewImg" => BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_preview.jpg",
 "year" => "2013",
 "yearClass" => "twenty13",
 "location" => "Autstin, Texas",
 "photographer" => "Rachel Cruz",
 "detailOne" => BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_detail1.jpg",
 "detailTwo" => BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_detail2.jpg",
 "detailThree" => BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_detail3.jpg",
 "detailFour" => BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_detail4.jpg",
 "description" => "lorem ipsum and shit",
 "detailOneSum" => "lorem ipsum",
 "detailTwoSum" => "lorem ipsum",
 "detailThreeSum" => "lorem ipsum",
 "detailFourSum" => "Lorem ipsum",
 "materials" => array("matOne","matTwo","matThree"),
 "materialImg" => array(BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_mat1.jpg",BASE_URL        .             "images/bungalow_mat2.jpg",BASE_URL ."images/bungalow_mat3.jpg"),
"testamonialImg" => BASE_URL ."images/client.jpg",
"testamonial" => "Cabin Is Great!"
);
```

And then in the project.php page I access the individual projects with

```
 $project_id = $_GET["id"];
 $project = $projects[$project_id];
```

Would that effect anything? thanks I am a total newb at this

This was my last attempt with the Rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^project.php$ /projects/%1/? [R=301]
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: What happens? What happens not? Why do projects beome shirts now? What does the RewriteLog say? Where is that .htaccess located relative to the document_root? Why don't you just adjust the links in the HTML pages?

Comment: Mario thank for pointing that out shirts was just from a code snippet I was referring to and i forgot to change it when I was typing here. The htaccess file is in the root of the directory. and currently I just get 404 requested url not found on server. And what do you mean by adjusting the links on the html pages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` character matches the beginning of the path but the path in the URL starts with `webcampaign` not `project.php`.

Try dropping the `^` from your `RewriteRule`. I also think you need to drop the `/projects/` from the redirect URL since it looks like that is the directory the .htaccess resides in.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webcampaign/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule project.php$ projects/%1? [R=301]
```

**EDIT:**

So based on your updated question it seems you want the inverse of what was requested as the rewrite module only rewrites incoming URLs, not those that your script outputs.

First thing is in your HTML output to change your links to the format that is to be displayed. This is what the commenter meant by "adjusting the links on the html pages".

```
echo '<a href="http://localhost/webcampaign/projects/1917-Bungalow">1917 Bungalow</a>';
```

Next use these new `.htaccess` rules to rewrite the above URL to your project.php page with the correct `id` parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webcampaign/

RewriteRule projects/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ projects/project.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this and it is still not working right, I have posted a photo of the file structure to possibly clarify. Thank you for the help

Comment: @VinceBrown: I've updated the answer. This rewrite works when tested on my localhost using your file structure.

Comment: Thank you that redirect was what i was looking for and works perfectly. If I could bother you with one more question, Unfortunately I still get 404 and I think it has to do with how my project.php template is set up. I have learned Databases yet so I just have all projects stored in an array and which I use a GET variable in the project.php page to access. Would this affect the redirect? I am editing the original post to include that information if you could take a look Thank you literally saving me hours right now.

Comment: That fixed everything thank you Cole, I just started with web dev this past year and its developers like you that are willing to take valuable time out their day to help the newbs that makes this field amazing.

Cheers have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(webcampaign/projects)/project\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(webcampaign/projects)/([^/]+)/?$ $1?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```